# autohotkey 2.0 call to nonexistent function winset

Tags: autohotkey

Happens with the popular example for autohotkey script for making a window Always-on-top

```
^SPACE::  Winset, Alwaysontop, , A
```

Answer (score 1):

It is documented on AHK website: https://autohotkey.com/v2/v2-changes.htm

> Sub-commands of WinGet, WinSet and Process have been replaced with individual functions...

So it is a simple change to:

```
^SPACE::  WinSetAlwaysOnTop, , A
```

Comment: And you might want it to toggle.
I had to add -1 for it to toggle when I upgraded to Ahk 2
^SPACE::  WinSetAlwaysOnTop -1 , A